# R - Created package documented with roxygen2 is there a way to create a PDF of all the functions documentation?

Tags: r

As I explained in the question, I made an R package using devtools and roxygen2. When I type `?function` the roxygen2 documentation displays in the Rstudio window and looks similar to the more mainstream packages.  Is there a way to create the pdf R documentation like what gets created for those mainstream packages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if `devtools` provides a way to do this, but at the command line, run

```
R CMD Rd2pdf pkgdir
```

where pkgdir is the directory containing the package.

Answer (score 0):

With devtools:

```
devtools::build_manual()
```